# Reflect Project Solution at design-time

Tags: visual-studio, reflection, projects-and-solutions, design-time

Good night guys,
i have a little problem ...

For my current project, i must reflect the whole solution on each type which inherits "IPropertyValidator".

Is there any way to reflect the solution at **design-time**?

I just tried it this way. VS hangs for a second on loading, but there are no results:

```
            PossibleValidatorTypes = new List<Type>();

        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IPropertyValidator)))
                    PossibleValidatorTypes.Add(type);
            }
        }
```

How could i do this?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (typeof(IPropertyValidator).IsAssignableFrom (type))
                    PossibleValidatorTypes.Add(type);
            }
```

Comment: No that doesn´t work. But more than mine...
It shows "Object" and "IPropertyValidator", but not the real classes...

Comment: I just found the following forum topic: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/ca9e6cd1-2657-496b-83af-7694146597e2/

The problem is, i can´t test it, because my UITypeEditor throws exceptions and my TypeConverter won´t work :D

But for now i go sleeping :)